# What is the actual meaning of authenticated in principal href for ACL Request for Caldav?

Tags: acl, webdav, caldav

I am currently implementing the `HTTP ACL Request` for caldav.

In the following XML document, there is an  tag in principal:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<D:acl xmlns:D="DAV:">
    <D:ace>
        <D:principal>
            <D:authenticated/>
        </D:principal>
        <D:grant>
            <D:privilege><D:read-current-user-privilege-set/></D:privilege>
        </D:grant>
    </D:ace>
</D:acl>
```

With **target**

```
 URI: /user/2/caldav/calreadtoauth/
where /user/2/caldav/ is user path of calendar collection
```

and calreadtoauth is the calendar name.

and I would like to know the actual meaning of it.

Here are the possible options for the target principal of "" for my understanding:

1. Refers to users who made the request are authenticated with the HTTP Authentication (Basic or Digest)
2. Refers to users who have privileges for the target URI (owner, admin or users who have right access the URI base on proper mapping)

I may be wrong and please sincerely give me some suggestion for the implementation of it or the number of options which is closest to the solution. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"authenticated" is the name of a group in the access control protocol spec which is defined to include the currently authenticated user. So the answer is 1) above :)